# Javascript function parameter not available in ajax calls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a HTML page where for a button click, I am calling a javascript function. The function has a parameter that comes from a html field. And I have to load another html page (its asp.net MVC3) based on the input parameter.

In the html page:

```
        <input type="radio" id="selected" name="selected" onclick="javascript:handleselect(this);" value=@item.ProjectID />
```

In the same code, i have the javascript..

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    function handleselect(myRadio) {      
         $.get('@Url.Action("Details", "ProjList", new { id = myRadio.value })', 
         async: false,
         function (viewResult) {
             $("#some-container").html(viewResult);
             alert(viewResult);
         });
     });

</script>
```

This is my sample script. However, i am getting an error like "The name 'myRadio' does not exist in the current context'.

The HTML code

I tried to look at all possible solutions. Please can someone help me?

Regards.
Hari

Comment: Show Code where you have defined myRadio

Comment: does myRadio.value not need to be outside the string? What do you get if you do alert(myRadio.value); in the first line of this function?

Comment: I get the right value. Am not getting the result only if its inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you function would be like

```
 function handleselect(myRadio) {      
      $.get('@Url.Action("Details", "ProjList")', { 
         id: $(myRadio).val() 
      },
      function (viewResult) {
          $("#some-container").html(viewResult);
          alert(viewResult);
      });
  });
```

or

```
 function handleselect(myRadio) {      
      $.get('@Url.Action("Details", "ProjList")', { 
         id: $(myRadio).attr('value') 
      },
      function (viewResult) {
          $("#some-container").html(viewResult);
          alert(viewResult);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Now, I am getting an error in the HTML code: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected". Did I miss anything?

Comment: @Hariprasauth Ramamoorthy: do an alert $(myRadio).val(), what r u getting. Second is there any error in console

Comment: Its working fine now!!!!!!!!! :) Thanks a million.. It was because of a missing bracket! Bad on me!

Answer (score 0):

use this - `'@Url.Action("Details", "ProjList", new { id = myRadio.value})`

or if u need to have the value of the **value tag** use this Javascript statement-

```
'@Url.Action("Details", "ProjList", new { id = '+myRadio.getAttribute("value")+'})'
```

**EDIT:**

```
    function handleselect(myRadio) { 
var url = @Url.Action("Details", "ProjList", new { id = myRadio.getAttribute("value")});     
         $.get(url, 
         async: false,
         function (viewResult) {
             $("#some-container").html(viewResult);
             alert(viewResult);
         });
     });
```

then-

Comment: <input type="radio" id="selected" name="selected" onclick="javascript:handleselect(this);" value=@item.ProjectID />

Comment: do u need the value of the html attribute value in the tag?

Comment: i want the value as I am dynamically changing the value.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Now, I am getting an error in the HTML code: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected". Did I miss anything?

Comment: that means u need @item.ProjectID?

Answer (score 0):

`myRadio` is a client side variable, it is not available in the server side

```
function handleselect(myRadio) {
    $.get('@Url.Action("Details", "ProjList")', { 
        id: myRadio.value 
    }, function (viewResult) {
              $("#some-container").html(viewResult);
              alert(viewResult);
          });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Now, I am getting an error in the HTML code: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected". Did I miss anything?

Comment: @HariprasauthRamamoorthy can you share how `handleselect` is called

Answer (score 0):

The razor engine interprets the urlhelper and doesn't know about your client code. That's the reason you cannot use your variable with `Url.Action`. You can try this instead:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("Details", "ProjList")?id=' + myRadio.value, 
    function (viewResult) {
        $("#some-container").html(viewResult);
        alert(viewResult);
    });
```

or another option is to use the data argument:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("Details", "ProjList")', { id: myRadio.value}, 
        function (viewResult) {
            $("#some-container").html(viewResult);
            alert(viewResult);
        });
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Now, I am getting an error in the HTML code: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected". Did I miss anything?

Comment: How do you call `handleselect`? Please edit your question and add the relevant code there.

Comment: ah wait, I don't think your code will run at all. The `async:false` is not a valid argument for `$.get`.

Comment: tried removing the assync: false line. its still giving the same error as "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected".

Comment: Have you used something like firebug to see where the error is pointing you?

Comment: no. Firebug (may be, i am dont know) is not giving an error.dump here. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the value of radio button try it like this

```
<input type="radio" id="selected" name="selected" onclick="javascript:handleselect(this.value);" value=@item.ProjectID />
```

or like this

```
<input type="radio" id="selected" name="selected" onclick="javascript:handleselect(@item.ProjectID);" value=@item.ProjectID />
```

And in the function you directly consume this value

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    function handleselect(myRadioValue) {      
         $.get('@Url.Action("Details", "ProjList", new { id ='+myRadioValue+'})'), 
         async: false,
         function (viewResult) {
             $("#some-container").html(viewResult);
             alert(viewResult);
         });
     });

</script>
```